# Repeating rows based on the collective count mentioned in the respective columns

Tags: r

How to repeat the rows per the count mentioned in their respective columns (considering multiple columns) in R?

```
data <- data.frame(
 city=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"),
 score=c(83,94,1,21,2,3,0),
 J=c(2,0,1,0,3,0,0),
 K=c(0,2,0,3,0,1,0),
 L=c(1,1,0,4,0,0,0))
data
```

**Original data frame**:

[image]

**Required data frame**:

[image]

Considering all column count, P.S. City D which is being repeated 4 times out of which 3 rows in column k have count 1 and 4 rows against column L has count 1 with respect to City D.

Comment: Why does "G" show up in your desired output? And why does column "L" contain a 0 in row 3, not a 1 as in row 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, lapply(.SD, function(x){
    g <- pmax(max(unlist(.SD)), 1)
    rep(1:0, c(x, g - x)) }), by = .(city, score)]

#     city score number number2 number3
#  1:    A    83      1       0       1
#  2:    A    83      1       0       0
#  3:    B    94      0       1       1
#  4:    B    94      0       1       0
#  5:    C     1      1       0       0
#  6:    D    21      0       1       1
#  7:    D    21      0       1       1
#  8:    D    21      0       1       1
#  9:    D    21      0       0       1
# 10:    E     2      1       0       0
# 11:    E     2      1       0       0
# 12:    E     2      1       0       0
# 13:    F     3      0       1       0
# 14:    G     0      0       0       0
```

Rows with all numbers equal to zero are properly handled. Replace `g <- pmax(max(unlist(.SD)), 1)` with `g <- max(unlist(.SD))` if you do not want such rows:

```
data[, lapply(.SD, function(x){
    g <- max(unlist(.SD))
    rep(1:0, c(x, g - x)) }), by = .(city, score)]
```

Comment: @AndreElrico, thanks. Actually, I was thinking about using `transpose` at first thought too.

Comment: That's really awesome! Thanks @mt1022

Comment: Hi @mt1022: I am really amazed to see very simple solution of yours, i never got the opportunity to learn this kind of skills in R. Can you please help me to suggest any relevant tutorials/ articles from where i can upgrade my R skills on data manipulation?

Comment: Any comment on `do.call(pmax, .SD)` versus `max(unlist(.SD))`? I would normally do the former.

Comment: can simplify `c(rep(1, x), rep(0, g - x))` to `rep(1:0, c(x, g - x))`.

Comment: @nikki, `data.table` is a powerful package for data manipulation. If you want to give it a try, I suggest you start with  [vignettes here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: @snoram, my criteria is efficiency and then simplicity. Regarding `rep(1:0 ...)`, good point. It is simpler and more efficient. (I edited the answer following your suggestion!) Regarding `do.call(pmax, .SD)`, It is slower than `max(unlist(.SD))` for the current case. However, it makes little difference if the dataset is not too large. To be honest, I use `max(unlist(.SD))` beause it came into my mind first :).

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` solution:

**data:** (make sure you don't have factors `stringsAsFactors = F`)

```
data <- data.frame(
    city=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"),
    score=c(83,94,1,21,2,3,0),
    number=c(2,0,1,0,3,0,0),
    number2=c(0,2,0,3,0,1,0),
    number3=c(1,1,0,4,0,0,0),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**code:** (let's have a function `fun1` that does the work for us)

```
data.table::setDT(data)

fun1 <- function(x) {
    transpose(
        transpose(
            lapply(x, function(u) if(u != 0) rep(1,u) else 0), fill = 0
        )
    )
}

data[, structure(fun1(.SD), .Names = names(.SD)), by = c("city","score")]
```

**result:**

```
 #   city score number number2 number3
 #1:    A    83      1       0       1
 #2:    A    83      1       0       0
 #3:    B    94      0       1       1
 #4:    B    94      0       1       0
 #5:    C     1      1       0       0
 #6:    D    21      0       1       1
 #7:    D    21      0       1       1
 #8:    D    21      0       1       1
 #9:    D    21      0       0       1
#10:    E     2      1       0       0
#11:    E     2      1       0       0
#12:    E     2      1       0       0
#13:    F     3      0       1       0
#14:    G     0      0       0       0
```

Comment: Thats perfect, Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Andre Elrico: I am really amazed to see a very simple solution of yours, i never got the opportunity to learn this kind of skills in R. Can you please help me to suggest any relevant tutorials/ articles from where i can upgrade my R skills on data manipulation?

Comment: @nikki, just learn `base::`, `data.table::` and `tidyverse::`. I learned a lot on this site when I see how one thing can be solved with n different ways. Always read the "f****** manual" for every function. So for e.g. type `?transpose` into console.

Answer (score 1):

**Note that there are some mistakes in the expected output based on the sample data you provide (see @markus comment).**

Here is a `tidyverse` option using `splitstackshape::cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)   
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("number")), funs(toString(rep(1, .)))) %>%
    group_by(city) %>%
    cSplit(grep("^number", names(data), value = T), direction = "long") %>%
    filter_at(vars(starts_with("number")), any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
    replace(., is.na(.), 0)
#   city score number number2 number3
#1     A    83      1       0       1
#2     A    83      1       0       0
#3     B    94      0       1       1
#4     B    94      0       1       0
#5     C     1      1       0       0
#6     D    21      0       1       1
#7     D    21      0       1       1
#8     D    21      0       1       1
#9     D    21      0       0       1
#10    E     2      1       0       0
#11    E     2      1       0       0
#12    E     2      1       0       0
#13    F     3      0       1       0
```

Explanation: The idea is to replace every `number` entry with a `vector` of the number of `1`s corresponding to its value, which we in turn convert to a comma-separated `character` vector with `toString`. We then use `splitstackshape::cSplit` to split those entries into multiple rows, remove all-`NA` rows and replace `NA`s with `0`s.

Comment: please add imports for `magrittr`, `dplyr`

Comment: Nicely Done, Thanks!